# IAP - can fetch free subscription products but not paid products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm experimenting with IAP and have added some test products to iTunes Connect.

However I am finding that a call to retrieve the products using SKProductsRequest is only successful if the product type is "Free Subscription", if I create a product of type "Consumable" or "Non-Renewing" for example then their product id's are returned in the SKProductsRequest.invalidProductIdentifiers and not the SKProductsRequest.products array.

Why can I not retrieve paid products but the free subscriptions ones ok?

(App has not been submitted to the app store, the iTunes connect app account and its products and the device has been setup up for testing IAP in accordance with the Apple iAP testing documentation https://web.archive.org/web/20171108103850/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)

Comment: Have you checked the status of the IAP products you are trying to test?

Comment: The status for all the products, working and non working is identical, and is "Waiting for Screenshot". Which is the correct status for test products. All of them are also cleared for sale.

Comment: Make sure you double check your product identifiers, it might be that simple

Comment: Its not that. I have tried copying/pasting the product ids from iTunes directly into the code. Also I have tried using product ids as simple as "a" and b" so there is opportunity for mis-typing.

Answer (score 3):

I have an app with Non-Renewing subscription IAP in it and I was able to test the paid subscriptions before submitting the app.  So it is possible.  Here is something to try.

1. Open the settings app
2. Go to iTunes and App Store
3. Log out of your iTunes account and DON'T log into any account here
4. Run your app
5. Start the IAP
6. If you get prompted for your iTunes account log in with you iTunes connect test account.

I am not sure if that will keep the paid IAPs from fetching.  You do have to do these steps to purchase a paid IAP in your debug build.

Be sure you NEVER log in with your iTunes connect test account in the settings and you only log in with it when prompted in your app.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I have previously done those steps.

Comment: I am not sure then.  You want to make sure you are connected to the sandbox IAP environment and not the production IAP environment.  I don't remember doing anything else "special" to get it working once I was using the sandbox IAP.

Comment: How does one connect to the sandbox rather than the production environment when making a call to SKProductsRequest:start to fetch the product ids?

Comment: You connect to the sandbox IAP with the instructions above.  Basically, you want to not be logged into an iTunes account and run your app signed with a dev or ad hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: The connection to the sandbox/non sandbox only occurs at the point a purchase is made. My question in the comment above and point is that **at the time the call to SKProductsRequest:start is made** there is no explicit call to a url made nor is the user is logged into any iTunes account. Therefore the app has no control over sandbox/non sandbox for SKProductRequest.

Comment: Ahh, yes good point.  I am actually not sure.  In my app I was able to get SKProductRequest to return IAPs that were not yet approved for sale.  I assumed that meant it was a sandbox connection and that sandbox connections returned all IAPs, not just approved ones.  But I am actually not sure how that works.

Comment: I am a bit stumped by your issue.  I have been doing IAPs since iOS 3.0 when they were introduced.  About 95% of the issues I have hit with them has been around the sandbox environment.  I have never seen your issue.  I have worked on apps with over 1,800 IAPs and apps with non-renewing subscriptions.

Comment: Might it be contract related as indicated in the other answer? My research indicates that accepting the contract is not required for testing.

Comment: I am not sure.  In my apps I had already accepted the contracts before doing IAP testing.

Comment: Log out isn't needed anymore starting with iOS 12: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions

Answer (score 1):

Have you accepted the contract in iTunes Connect? They have 2 different contracts for free applications and paid applications.

If you want to offer paid content, you need to accept the contract in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Accepting the contract is something which is not supposed to be necessary (according to multiple sources I have seen) for testing. Yes it is necessary for the final product, but it is not a requirement at the testing stage. However I've exhausted all other options so could try this as a last resort (but won't get the chance for a few days).